# If $f$ is continuous almost everywhere, must there exist a function $g$ such that $g=f$ almost everywhere and $g$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $f$ is continuous almost everywhere, must there exist a function $g$ such that $g=f$ almost everywhere and $g$ is continuous?
I have one example that shows it could happen. Let $f$ be defined as $1$ on irrationals and $0$ the rationals. Then the constant function $g$ defined as $1$ everywhere is such that: $g=f$ a.e. and $g$ is continuous. Thus, the statement may be true, but I am not able to show why. Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Consider $f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \ge 0\\ 0 & x < 0\end{cases} $$
$f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R -\{0\}$, but cannot be made into a continuous function by change on a set of measure zero.

Comment: I was thinking about this example and I don't know how to prove that $f$ cannot be made into a continuous function just by changing it on a set of measure zero, could you help me to show this?

Comment: @user156441 Feel free to ask this as a new question ...

Comment: @martini does that marked as duplicate